# Generating a signed URL for AWS S3

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-ios

I'm trying to create a signed url for AWS S3, i just want the URL for a file in my bucket, i don't want to use it for upload/download.

I've tried AFNetworking, following the steps on Amazons documentation and am now using the AWS iOS SDK.

So far i have this:

```
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSStaticCredentialsProvider        credentialsWithAccessKey:@"Access Key" secretKey:@"secret key"];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration    configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSWest2  credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder * urlBuilder  = [[AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder alloc]       initWithConfiguration:configuration];

AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest *preSignedURLRequest = [AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest new];
preSignedURLRequest.bucket = @"bucket-name";
preSignedURLRequest.key = @"/filename";
preSignedURLRequest.HTTPMethod = AWSHTTPMethodGET;
preSignedURLRequest.expires = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600];

 NSURL *preSignedURL = [urlBuilder getPreSignedURL:preSignedURLRequest];

NSLog(@"%@", preSignedURL);
```

I'm getting a lot of errors about the code being depreciated, but more importantly i Know that the method getPreSignedURL returns a type (AWSTask *), my question is how to turn a AWSTask into the signed url?

Also i don't plan on leaving the keys in my code this is just temporary for testing.

If anyone could help me find how to get the preSignedURL that'd be a great help.
Thanks

Comment: Ben, I am struggling with the same errors. Did you get the solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried [S3BackgroundTransfer-Sample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples)? It should help you get started.

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the asked question. Answer should be only for "Generating a signed URL for AWS S3" not for transferring, uploading or downloading.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Taming the AWS framework to upload a large file to S3](http://www.mobdesignapps.fr/blog/2016/10/26/uploading-large-file-to-aws-s3-in-the-background?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=response&utm_campaign=awareness&utm_term=%2031073380) it also covers generating a pre-signed URL in swift

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the asked question. Answer should be only for "Generating a signed URL for AWS S3" not for uploading or downloading

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Amit Anmol, if you check the article you'll see that Generating a pre-signed URL is covered in the article under the "CREATE THE PARTS' UPLOAD REQUESTS" section.

Answer (score -2):

I am assuming you are trying to handle background upload/downloads. For this purpose you can use `AWSS3TransferUtility`.

You can read more details on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transferutility.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Link-only answers are not helpful, especially if the link should break.  Please provide the important aspects to your answer here, and provide links for reference.

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the asked question. Answer should be only for "Generating a signed URL for AWS S3" not for uploading or downloading.